# Ошибка в задаче

Tags: c++

Вот собственно текст задачи:

> Известный художник решил написать новый шедевр. После многих дней усердной работы он захотел исследовать свое творение. Художник вспомнил, что картина писалась следующим образом: сначала был взят белый холст, имеющий форму прямоугольника шириной w и высотой h. Затем художник нарисовал на этом холсте n прямоугольников со сторонами,   параллельными сторонам холста и вершинами, расположенными в целочисленных координатах. Помогите  художнику определить площадь незакрашенной части холста.
>
> Входные данные
>
> Первая строка входного файла INPUT.TXT содержит два натуральных числа w и h (1 ≤ w, h ≤ 100). Во второй строке записано целое число n (1 ≤ n ≤ 5000) – количество прямоугольников. Следующие n строк содержат информацию о всех прямоугольниках. Каждая строка описывает один прямоугольник в виде четырех чисел x1, y1, x2, y2 , где (x1, y1) и (x2, y2) – координаты левого нижнего и правого верхнего угла прямоугольника соответственно.
>
> Выходные данные
>
> Выведите в выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT одно целое число – площадь незакрашенной части холста. P.S прямоугольники могут быть наложенны друг на друга:

Тесты:

```
Input:

  5 5
  2
  1 1 3 3
  2 2 4 4          Output:18 -(не работает)

Input:

  6 7
  3
  0 0 5 5
  1 1 4 4
  2 2 3 3      output: 17 (работает)
```

Мой вариант:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int w, h, i, j, n, x1, x2, y1, y2, Sum = 0;

    ifstream input("input.txt");
    ofstream output("output.txt");
    input >> w >> h >> n;

    int ar[h][w];

    while (n > 0) {
        input >> x1 >> y1 >> x2 >> y2;
        for (i = y1 + 1; i <= y2; i++) {
            for (j = x1 + 1; j <= x2; j++) {
                ar[i][j] = 1;
            }
        }
        n--;
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= h; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= w; j++) {
            if (ar[i][j] != 1) {
                Sum++;
            }
        }
    }

    output << Sum;
}
```

Подскажите, где ошибка?

P.S Вот линк на [оригинал](http://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=27) задачи.

Разобрался сам, можно закрывать:

Если кому -то интересно вот правильный вариант:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

  int main()  {

  int w, h, i, j, n, x1, x2, y1, y2, Sum = 0;

  ifstream input("input.txt");  
  ofstream output("output.txt");
  input >> w >> h >> n;

  int ar[100][100];

  for ( i = 0; i < h; ++i){  
      for( j = 0; j < w; ++j){  
              ar[i][j] = 0;  
      }  
  }

  while (n > 0) {  
      input >> x1 >> y1 >> x2 >> y2;

      for (i = y1; i < y2; i++) {  
          for (j = x1; j <x2; j++) {  
              ar[i][j] = 1;  
          }  
      }  
      n--;  
  }

  for (i = 0; i < h; i++) {  
      for (j = 0; j < w; j++) {  
          if (ar[i][j] == 0) {  
              Sum++;  
          }  
      }  
  }

  output << Sum;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Следующий код не очень быстр, но его скорости достаточно для задачи (самый долгий тест 0,075)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory.h>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);

    bool a[150][150]; // С запасом, да побольше, благо памяти 16 метров
    int c = 0,w,h,n;
    memset(a,0,sizeof(a)); // Зануляем массив

    cin >> w >> h >> n;

    for(int ii = 0; ii<n; ++ii) // Запускаем цикл по количеству прямоугольников
    {
        int x1,x2,y1,y2;
        cin >> x1 >> y1 >> x2 >> y2; // Считываем прямоугольник
        for(int i = x1; i < x2; ++i)
            for(int j = y1; j < y2; ++j)
            a[i][j] = true;   // И помечаем его в массиве
    }

     for(int i = 0; i < h; ++i)
            for(int j = 0; j < w; ++j)
            if (a[i][j]) c++; // Считаем количество закрашеных ячеек

    cout << w*h - c << endl; // Выводим количество незакрашеных ячеек
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Зачем запас 150, если по условию ширина и высота не больше 100? Программу можно сделать и с одним циклом по моему алгоритму из моего ответа.

 Строку

    a[i][j] = true;   // И помечаем его в массиве
можно заменить на

    if(!a[i][j]) c--, a[i][j]=true;

Только перед выполнением всего цикла надо проинициализировать `c=w*h`.
 Цикл ниже будет не нужен.

Comment: Я на acmp всегда запас делаю, т.к. есть задачи, где условие не очень соответствует тестам (либо не проверены простейшие случаи) поэтому на всякий.

Answer (score 1):

> Ошибка в задаче

Может быть, всё-таки, ошибка в решении задачи?

```
input>>w>>h>>n;
int ar[h][w];
```

По стандарту такое компилироваться не должно. Размер массива должен быть известен во время компиляции.

Алгоритм такой:

1. Объявляешь наибольший массив:

   bool array[100][100]={0};
2. Вычисляешь площадь пустого холста:

   Area=w*h;
3. Циклом проходишься по всем прямоугольникам и в двойном цикле устанавливаешь соответствующие ячейки в true. Если они до этого были false, уменьшаешь площадь свободного места Area на 1.
4. Выводишь Area.

Answer (score 0):

А инициализировать массив ar нулями кто будет?

Comment: Там это не обязательно.